# Mini Ajax File Upload Form not working on opera

Tags: ajax, image, file, file-upload

> Mini Ajax File Upload Form not working on opera.

I just download and test it with Firefox and Chrome and its work fine. Can anyone know how to make this for opera browser?

Download Mini Ajax File Upload Form http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/

Comment: Problem solved. In opera browser the file input  button should not be 
'display:none'. It must hide by 'position:absolute' and give 'top:-100px' or position that hide the file input button from the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mini Ajax File Upload Form there is a file input that styled as display none. And costume button has been designed as browse button. This button click fires actual file input click event. So actual file input must be hidden from the user. Opera just can't identify this hidden element. So do these steps.

1. Style container of file input as position:relative; overflow:hidden
2. Style file input as Display:block; position:absolute; top:-50; left:0

This style will hide the file input. I have try this. Its works